# What flower is this grown in Southern China

Tags: species-identification, flowers

It is grown in Tropical Southern China. It is not wild.[image]

Comment: Google image search, first result, thinks that your photo is a mexican petunia. I find the color fairly specific, and the leaves fairly dark, so i tried a google image search: https://www.google.fr/search?q=mexican+petunia&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwm8vigNjdAhVjc98KHeOiAgQQ_AUIDigB&biw=898&bih=461#imgdii=DDoju-SfrCdmOM:&imgrc=xC36dN7qAGPh0M:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google images sais that it's a mexican petunia, I think it's right due to the good focus of your image, and the different attributes of the photo. [image]

http://www.gardenality.com/ImageViewer/?id=2116&IUID=3&RID=88#imageId=2116